# Extract RSA Public Key from public Certificate

Tags: certificate, openssl, rsa

I have public certificate with 2048 bit RSA public key for encrypt data.
I need use openssl to extract this public key.
Certyficate is PEM .cer file, and extracted key should be PEM too.

I use command to extract Public key

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.cer  > pubkey.pem
```

And output is:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr5qMxLWtgkId2oRUfnPf
> 6MX+UouBQKOzyfG0J9LW9yya8Nr+ilPTSPp+hSBL/TD1ijUZ2RClyegnrojOKHS7
> kp1ZFDQJwmKSW660NKeLbyu2fbcJFBuDmSVK8XwRsUaIpf4eixqx5wAZg8q64kJ9
> R9e07WPqrC2+8p2F/7zlKsZ263CWZ/xE0M6I4RiKSA24iaiGVrppnIrX1oX2v/dq
> UNaQL3uIgH1WWtf4apnDA7MVei2Iz2NjFzLJ569wxzO92XBUrcEkqA7Xx0or6xij
> h0oFKxsygNqHzK3qf56McRi/xy1VFrGQsiZL1u4+cdIAu5/tWaecLFl0UOBBbYxz
> 9QIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

And I try to convert it to RSA Public key with PKCS#1 padding and AN1 encoding

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in cert.cer -outform PEM -pubkey -nocert -out pubkeyRSA.pem
```

And output is

> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBCgKCAQEAr5qMxLWtgkId2oRUfnPf6MX+UouBQKOzyfG0J9LW9yya8Nr+ilPT
> SPp+hSBL/TD1ijUZ2RClyegnrojOKHS7kp1ZFDQJwmKSW660NKeLbyu2fbcJFBuD
> mSVK8XwRsUaIpf4eixqx5wAZg8q64kJ9R9e07WPqrC2+8p2F/7zlKsZ263CWZ/xE
> 0M6I4RiKSA24iaiGVrppnIrX1oX2v/dqUNaQL3uIgH1WWtf4apnDA7MVei2Iz2Nj
> FzLJ569wxzO92XBUrcEkqA7Xx0or6xijh0oFKxsygNqHzK3qf56McRi/xy1VFrGQ
> siZL1u4+cdIAu5/tWaecLFl0UOBBbYxz9QIDAQAB
> -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

After decode it with Base64 and used to encrypt data, server show me an error, that encrypted key is wrong. Also, trying to load this keys to LockBox library for Delphi programs, it throws an exception "Wrong asymetric key"

The certificate is:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFGTCCBAGgAwIBAgITYwABPJqEcB3zrmJ2agABAAE8mjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwF
> ADBdMRIwEAYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYCcGwxEzARBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgNnb3YxEjAQ
> BgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgJtZjEeMBwGA1UEAxMVUmVzb3J0IEZpbmFuc293IEkxIENB
> MB4XDTIwMDcyMzExMjgyM1oXDTIyMDcyMzExMjgyM1owgZExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlBM
> MRQwEgYDVQQIEwttYXpvd2llY2tpZTERMA8GA1UEBxMIV2Fyc3phd2ExHzAdBgNV
> BAoMFk1pbmlzdGVyc3R3byBGaW5hbnPDs3cxHDAaBgNVBAsTE0FwbGlrYWNqZSBL
> cnl0eWN6bmUxGjAYBgNVBAMTEWV0dy10c3QubWYuZ292LnBsMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
> 9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr5qMxLWtgkId2oRUfnPf6MX+UouBQKOzyfG0
> J9LW9yya8Nr+ilPTSPp+hSBL/TD1ijUZ2RClyegnrojOKHS7kp1ZFDQJwmKSW660
> NKeLbyu2fbcJFBuDmSVK8XwRsUaIpf4eixqx5wAZg8q64kJ9R9e07WPqrC2+8p2F
> /7zlKsZ263CWZ/xE0M6I4RiKSA24iaiGVrppnIrX1oX2v/dqUNaQL3uIgH1WWtf4
> apnDA7MVei2Iz2NjFzLJ569wxzO92XBUrcEkqA7Xx0or6xijh0oFKxsygNqHzK3q
> f56McRi/xy1VFrGQsiZL1u4+cdIAu5/tWaecLFl0UOBBbYxz9QIDAQABo4IBmzCC
> AZcwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMD4GCSsGAQQBgjcVBwQxMC8GJysGAQQBgjcVCIS3
> mFWE7NgBhrmTDYO18X6DrtM2gUKEotdOhMuPDgIBZAIBDDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUnFcp
> uSFJZYUBUkIplCvJERbNN98wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUfR+t1nzLSol4VWy6EPLtM9Yx
> us0wRgYDVR0fBD8wPTA7oDmgN4Y1aHR0cDovL3BraS5tZi5nb3YucGwvY2RwL3Jl
> c29ydF9maW5hbnNvd19pMV9jYSgxKS5jcmwwdQYIKwYBBQUHAQEEaTBnMD4GCCsG
> AQUFBzAChjJodHRwOi8vcGtpLm1mLmdvdi5wbC9haWEvcmVzb3J0X2ZpbmFuc293
> X2kxX2NhLmNydDAlBggrBgEFBQcwAYYZaHR0cDovL3BraS5tZi5nb3YucGwvb2Nz
> cDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwJwYJKwYBBAGCNxUKBBow
> GDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATAKBggrBgEFBQcDAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFAAOCAQEAHatd
> TuoQDgaydiNDZFPvbvnqO0wmD/sH54LkXnf49hXHcGQRjhBc7xsSDbKzxHEORJ08
> wNWWJa0H8cbKCLytBq49FQnENYoi5sgMetM5XGqGSYHwFLTFyAf8A9af8rpqfAEY
> HwmL6iIjz6NmSD52i3owOaMCop4pyC+UU5CZDqBrYd10JY4bWRm5NPdjIga0+mDm
> hQYEkoW/AEQQam+VmyLsJFGtBl/kr5+EFIUFw8X2tFAubNTuxQsveLo91Q0lHtSt
> BMBJ7MYnJeFCGDeuPM65nJtCxexDfWfWSTZvGrdJSUooD5iFSZodCkReP7ZLiQmB
> dPB1oIhW3y/VUem3+A== -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Is it correctly trying to extract this key from the certificate?

Comment: Your second command is impossible because `x509` does not have a `-nocert` option; the only way to produce PEM type "RSA PUBLIC KEY" is not any form of `x509` but instead `openssl rsa -in pubkey.pem -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out -out pubkeyrsa.pem`. I have no idea what your server is doing or what LockBox is, and I don't do Delphi and even if I did programming would be offtopic here, so I can't help with anything else.

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you.